# SQL join rows from second table as columns

Tags: sql

This is probably a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it. Maybe I'm thinking about this backwards.

How do I format a query to return the results like this with the source tables below?

| Filename | Attr1 | Attr2 | Attr3 | Configuration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1.txt | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Default |
| file1.txt | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | First |

Documents Table

| DocumentID | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | file1.txt |

VariableValues table

| VariableID | DocumentID | ValueCache | ConfigurationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 1 | Val1 | 1 |
| 56 | 1 | Val2 | 1 |
| 172 | 1 | Val3 | 1 |
| 55 | 1 | Val1 | 2 |
| 56 | 1 | Val2 | 2 |
| 172 | 1 | Val3 | 2 |

Configuration Table

| ConfigurationID | ConfigName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Default |
| 2 | First |

I originally wrote this with subqueries

```
select top 10 d.Filename,   
(select ValueCache from VariableValue vv where d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and vv.VariableID = 55) as Description,
(select ValueCache from VariableValue vv where d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and vv.VariableID = 56) as PartNumber,
(select ValueCache from VariableValue vv where d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and vv.VariableID = 172) as CrossReference,
dc.ConfigurationName
FROM Documents d
INNER JOIN VariableValue vv ON d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID
inner join DocumentConfiguration dc ON dc.ConfigurationID = vv.ConfigurationID
```

But that doesn't handle configurations properly, the subqueries return multiple results when there are multiple configurations.  So I tried converting it to a table valued query, but this returns each variable on a separate line and I can't figure out how to transpose them.

```
  select top 10 d.Filename, d.DocumentID, ConfigurationID, d.CurrentStatusID

  into #temp
    FROM Documents d
INNER JOIN VariableValue vv ON d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID
WHERE vv.VariableID = 172 and ValueCache is not null


select t.Filename, vv.ValueCache, v.VariableName, s.Name from #temp t
inner join VariableValue vv ON t.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and t.ConfigurationID = vv.ConfigurationID
inner join Variable v ON vv.VariableID = v.VariableID and v.VariableID in (55, 56, 172)
inner join [Status] s ON s.StatusID = t.CurrentStatusID

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Search for *SQL Pivot rows* and your specific RDBMS.

Comment: What `RDBMS` you are using?

Comment: MSSQL is the RDBMS

Comment: Actually my subqueries solution worked out better. It wasn't performant: returned 3.3M rows in 3 minutes but I only needed to run it once. The subquery failed because there was another parameter that I needed to join on (revision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` function on your `INNER JOIN` query in two scenarios:

1st one: if the number of `ValueCache` values is known i.e. only `(val1, val2, val3)`

```
select Filename, Val1 as att1,  Val2 as att2, Val3 as att3, ConfigName  from
(
select Documents.Filename, VariableValues.ValueCache,Configuration.ConfigName
from 
Documents inner join VariableValues
on Documents.DocumentID=VariableValues.DocumentID
inner join Configuration
on Configuration.ConfigurationID = VariableValues.ConfigurationID
 ) D
PIVOT
  (MAX(ValueCache) for ValueCache in (Val1, Val2, Val3)) P
```

2nd one: if the number of `ValueCache` values is unknown then you can use `Dynamic SQL Query`

```
DECLARE @valCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlQr  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @valCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ValueCache) 
                    from VariableValues FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @sqlQr = 'SELECT Filename, ' + @valCols + ', ConfigName from 
(
select Documents.Filename, VariableValues.ValueCache,Configuration.ConfigName
from 
Documents inner join VariableValues
on Documents.DocumentID=VariableValues.DocumentID
inner join Configuration
on Configuration.ConfigurationID = VariableValues.ConfigurationID
 ) D
 PIVOT
(MAX(ValueCache) for ValueCache in ('+ @valCols+ ')) P'
execute(@sqlQr)
```

See the result form [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93ca0e3eebb6d2aebf8015f2c904c661).